# Literal content is not allowed within a 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone'

Tags: web-part, page-layout, 2016

I have got a custom page layout that I want to create web part zone in.

I have generated below code from Design Manager and added to my page layout.(I had to take screenshot as it is not rendered correctly in the question)

[image: Code]

When I try to load the page, I get below error;

[image: Error]

Does anyone have any suggestion regarding how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are adding the snippet in HTML file not in the ASPX. I faced the same issue, and turned out I was adding the snippet in ASPX page layout file. Once I added it in the HTML file, the same snippet worked.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same and yes, I'm adding this into the ASPX file. Where can I find an HTML file? There are no HTML files in the same folder.

Comment: Hi @K48 - sorry for late reply, if you are using SharePoint 2013 you will find both the HTML and ASPX files of OOB master pages in Master Page gallery. If you are working on custom master pages, start by using Design Manager.